# Copy file from one ubuntu to another ubuntu

Tags: backup, mysql, cron

By using `cron` job I've successfully created a backup of mysql database on the Ubuntu. Below is the command under `mysqldump.sh`

```
/opt/lampp/bin/./mysqldump -u root database-name | gzip >/db-backup/"mysql_db-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %T").sql.gz"
```

I'm running above using `cron` job below is the command of `cron` job

```
* * * * * /db-backup/mysqldump.sh
```

My question is, I don't want to create the sql backup file to the same ubuntu (IP: 192.168.2.10). Actually I need to copy the sql backup file to another ubuntu (IP: 192.168.2.11) which is in same network

I tried to change `cron` job command to `* * * * * /192.168.2.11/db-backup/mysqldump.sh` but sql backup file is not copying to `192.168.2.11/db-backup/`

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

You can send the backup file to the other Ubuntu using `rsync` or `scp` then you can delete the backup on your system or not

Use [this link](http://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/) for learning `rsync`

RSync useful options:

```
    -r                      --> Recursive
    -b                      --> Backup
    -u                      --> Update (--inplace, --append)
    -d                      --> Transfering dirs without recursive
    -l                      --> Copy symbolics as symbolics
    -p                      --> Preserve permissions 
    -E                      --> Preserve Executability
    -o                      --> Preserve OwenrShip
    -g                      --> Preserve Groups
    -t                      --> Preserve modifition time
    -z                      --> Compress
    -v                      --> Increase verbosity
    -a                      --> Archive mode
    -H                      --> Preserve hard links 
    -e                      --> To run shell command on the remote server
    -e <protocol>           --> Over that protocol (e.g. ssh)
    -h                      --> Human readable
    -P                      --> Show the progress during the progress (SMILE), Same as --progress
    --safe-link             --> Ignore symbolic links that point out of the tree
    --existing              --> Ignore creating new files       
    --ignore-existing       --> Ignore updating existing files
    --remove-source-files   --> Sender remove synced files
    --progress              --> Show the progress during the progress (SMILE)
    --log-file=FILE         --> Sending logs will be stored to FILE
    --include=PATTERN       --> Sync files that have PATTERN filter in themselves
    --exclude=PATTERN       --> Don't sync files that have PATTERN filter in themselves
    --max-size='SomeK'      --> Only send or recieve files less than SomeK
```

And some examples:

```
    rsync -t [Pattern (e.g. *.c)] [PurposeMachine]:Path
        Send all file with that pattern in the current dir to purpose machine in the path (if exist only send differences)
        e.g. rsync -t *.c foo:/src

    rsync -avz [Machine]:Path/dir PathHere :    
        Download all files recursivly that are in the dir directory to the PathHere/dir 
        File transfering is archive mode that means Symbolic links, devices, attributes, permissons, ownerships, etc are preseved
        e.g. rsync -avz foo:src/bar /data/tmp

    rsync -avz [Machine]:Path/dir/ PathHere :
        Download all files recursivly that are in the dir directory to the PathHere/ 
        File transfering is archive mode that means Symbolic links, devices, attributes, permissons, ownerships, etc are preseved
        e.g. rsync -avz foo:src/bar/ /data/tmp

    rsync -av NowHere/dir[/] /Dest :


    rsync -av [host]:: /Dest: [OR rsync -av [host]::moudle /Dest]
        All files in remote dir will be transfered
```

Comment: sql backup file is not a single file it is creating with current date and time so every time I have a sql backup file is creating with the new name like "mysql_bk_2010-08-02 10:40" and so on...

Comment: @shaji So what's the problem? You can use `rsync` on a directory and rsync won't send duplicates

Comment: I submit command from 192.168.2.10

 > rsync db_backup/ 192.168.2.11/db_backup

Now this error is appearing

skipping directory .
rsync: change_dir#3 "/192.168.2.11" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at main.c(712) [Receiver=3.1.0]

Please help on the above issue

Comment: I submitted another command "rsync -a ~/db_backup/ Administrator@192.168.2.11:db_backup" but this error appeared 


ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.11 port 22: Connection refused
 
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender] 

rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]

Comment: You must install ssh on your remote computer. To do so: `apt-get install openssh-server`

Comment: Please confirm, do I have to install it on both machines? both machines are on local network

Comment: I installed openssh-server on both machines and submitted this command (rsync -avz db_backup/ root@192.168.2.11:/db_backup/) than it asked me for the password. I entered the same password that I use to login that is same as root password but it shows "Permission denied"

Comment: You must enter remote computer password, And you must config ssh-server to accept root ssh if you are using root user.
To do so edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and uncomment `PermitRootLogin yes`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26510/discussion-between-shaji-and-m-fooladgar).

Comment: under /etc/ssh/ the sshd_config is not there. only ssh_config is there
and under ssh_config there is no PermitRootLogin. so I added this line under ssh_config

Comment: I found PermitRootLogin without-password under /etc/ssh/sshd_config